# How to center a group of inline divs within another div

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/95pR2/1/

Essentially what the title says, I am trying to center the numbers to the center.  This is taken from http://www.kevinresol.com/divslideshow/example.php

Something else that I am having an issue with is centering the facebook embedded div like button.  It is the similar issue of centering a div within another div.  I was able to get it to center by doing style="text-align:center" on the parent div, but doesn't work on the first issue (so I posted both). 
http://jsfiddle.net/qWJm5/1/

I'm pretty sure its related to correctly styling parent and child divs, but i've tried other stack overflow forums and they don't seem to work for example doing margin:0px auto;.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2nd fiddle: This page can't be seen by the current user. Please check page privacy and visibility settings.

Comment: Plus, the kevinresol.com link results in a 403, forbidden.

Comment: Is the second jsfiddle website not viewable at all, or just the final page?  It is essentially just an embedded div autogenerated by facebook from the following page (centering "wall" that is for example 200px wide in a 300 pixel wide div): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is automatically floating your control elements with an inline style, if you remove that line from `line:90` of your `jquery.divslideshow-1.2.js` script you can then style the control elements yourself. So, remove line:90, which reads:

```
.css('float','left')
```

And add the following CSS:

**CSS**

```
#dss .control-containter {
 text-align:center;
}

.controls {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

And all should be well.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/95pR2/7/

Comment: Just a comment but there are better scripts out there that are more flexible and allow you better control of your slide, such as the [jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle demo.  That answers the immediate question.  I will look into the jquery Cycle plugin.  Thsi was just the first one i came across that would for sure work with a div.

Answer (score 3):

Apply a `text-align: center;` to the parent div. Remove the `float:left` on the child divs, and make each child div an inline-block.